# Unable to restrict input such that min < mode < max

Tags: excel, operators, comparison-operators, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA function that restricts its inputs. It takes three arguments `min`, `mode`, and `max`, and needs to ensure that `min < mode < max`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Function TRIANGULAR(min As Double, mode As Double, max As Double)
    If min < mode < max Then
        TRIANGULAR = (min + mode + max) / 3
    Else
        MsgBox "min < mode < max", vbCritical
    End If
End Function
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If`'s don't work like that.

use

```
If (min < mode) and (mode < max) Then
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, i didn't know about that :) .... i have another question regarding "pivot tables", i hope you would help me with that too :)

Comment: @Rachit if Chris's answer has answered your question you can accept it by clicking the check mark beside this answer. It helps let others know that your problem has been solved. ([Plus a bunch of other stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/162918))